# Is using something like MakeHuman frowned upon while developing 3D games?

Tags: assets, education

I came across this interesting application called [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/), and I was wondering what developers in the gaming community thought about creating and exporting characters to Unity using this application. I'm not an artist, so a tool like this helps me create characters without having to pay someone else to model them from scratch.

If I were taking a class in game development, would it be permissible to use something like this to create characters rather than create them myself (in Blender or Maya, for example)? What benefits are there to consulting an artist rather than using tools like this?

Answer (score 3):

Employing an artist would give your game a specific aesthetic that will help it stand out,
but it's perfectly acceptable to use whatever tools available to make your game. Usually the assets produced by the more user friendly tools out there look sortof bland. You can usually tell when someone has been using the out-of-the-box assets from [Poser](http://poser.smithmicro.com/), for example.

Unless the class is *about* 3d modelling, the professor isn't going to care how you *make* your assets, as long as you don't steal another game's assets *and* call them your own, or use assets commercially that require a license.

Don't be afraid to dig into Blender, either. While you say you're not an artist, you don't have to have amazing realism right away, or ever. Start by making simple props, and keep looking at tutorials to learn new techniques. Your models don't have to be realistic, they just need to be different. Show us things we've never seen before instead of trying to beat people with more experience at their own game.

And don't make another zombie/survival/simulator game.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue when looking at any tool is legal, do I have the right to use it. MakeHuman allows just about any commercial and noncommercial usage of it's creations so  that's fine.

The second issue is if it's a good idea, this depends if you think you can create a better human or more fitting human then you should if you think your humans will not be so great then you probably shouldn't (unless it's a demand by your class).

Lastly remember efficiency the MakeHuman app does not appear to have a polygon slider meaning that it produces humans of one quality only, this can be difficult if you want to generate a large number of humans (to many polygons making them to slow) or if you want to generate movie quality (to few polygons, people will notice).

The advantage of asking an artist rather then using the tools yourself is that hopefully an artist will know better what he/she is doing and will produce better results, usually artists are more skilled with the more complex tools (blender and maya) and can therefor produce better results of course even then they might still not be better then a purpose build app such as MakeHuman.